# Join operation in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables Property and Rent I want to fetch the common records from both the tables. I have tried the code below but I am getting error. I want to know what mistake I have done.

This is my query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Property INNER JOIN Rent ON Property.Property_id=:Rent.propertyid",nativeQuery=true)
 public List<Property> ghgh();
```

The error I am getting:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [Rent.propertyid] [SELECT * FROM Property INNER JOIN Rent ON
>   Property.Property_id=:Rent.propertyid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon (`:`) marks a named parameter, for example:

```
SELECT p FROM Property p WHERE p.name = :name
```

In this case `:name` is a named parameter that has to be provided to make the query work.

You're using `:Rent.propertyid` in your query, which is why Hibernate throws an exception, saying that that named parameter isn't present (your method doesn't have any parameter).

Shouldn't you leave the colon away?

```java
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Property INNER JOIN Rent ON Property.Property_id=Rent.propertyid", nativeQuery=true)
```